# Strange buffering behavior in termios/stdlib

Tags: c, terminal, io, stdin, tty

I'm trying to disable buffering on my program's input/output so that characters are transmitted and received ASAP, but I'm not seeing the results I'd expect based on what I've read about buffering in the stdio and termios documentation. Here's a small example to explain what I mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int trapState;

void sigInt(int blah) {
    trapState++;
    if (trapState == 5) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int b = 0;
    trapState = 0;
    
    signal(SIGINT, &sigInt);
    
    while (1) {
        getchar();
        
        if (trapState > b) puts("boop\n");
        
        b = trapState;
    }
}
```

Straightforward enough: when you hit ^C, it should print a string, and then bail the fifth time, right?

Weirdly, however, the output doesn't show up on the terminal unless you hit ENTER; moreover, if you hit ^C more than once between hitting ENTER, *only one message is printed,* meaning that `getchar()` is blocking until end-of-line and the SIGINT handler is incrementing **b** more than once per iteration, even though `getchar()` is supposed to return EOF if there's no input. The SIGINT handler runs when it should, because it will dump immediately the fifth time around, but the program is stuck waiting on `getchar()` until the line buffer is filled.

So, okay, let's **A.** try to work around the buffering on stdio and **B.** account for multiple interrupts and see what happens:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int trapState;

void sigInt(int blah) {
    trapState++;
    if (trapState == 5) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int b = 0;
    trapState = 0;
    
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    
    signal(SIGINT, &sigInt);
    
    while (1) {
        while (trapState > b) {
            puts("boop\n");
            b++;
        }
        
        fflush(stdout);
        
        getchar();
    }
}
```

Multiple messages are now printed, but still only after ENTER is pressed, meaning that getchar() is still blocking, despite buffering being disabled on stdin. (And we can't check for EOF *before* calling getchar() since feof() is only guaranteed to reflect the state of a stream after the *last* operation.)

But the TTY driver *also* line-buffers by default. Is it getting hung up in there? Let's find out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>

int trapState;
struct termios t, z;

void sigInt(int blah) {
    trapState++;
    if (trapState == 5) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void dump() {
    tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &z);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int b = 0;
    trapState = 0;
    
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    
    tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &z);
    
    tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &t);
    t.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);
    t.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    t.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSAFLUSH, &t);
    fflush(stdout);
    
    signal(SIGINT, &sigInt);
    atexit(&dump);
    
    while (1) {
        while (trapState > b) {
            puts("boop\n");
            b++;
        }
        
        fflush(stdout);
        
        getchar();
        
        tcflush(fileno(stdin), TCIOFLUSH);
    }
}
```

*Same result.* I'm having a **heck** of a time figuring this out - does getchar() *ever* return EOF from stdin? Or does it just block until a character is read, indefinitely? This behavior seems to be standard - I got the same results on a Linux system and a BSD system - but it's not behaving the way I'd expect it to based on what the documentation I'm reading says. What am I missing here?

Comment: What's the documentation you're reading?

Comment: @they http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/ https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/termios.h.html https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Noncanonical-Input.html

Comment: @MC68020 Huh, thanks; but I'm still curious. Commenters on that say that it's not possible to do this via stdin, and the "solution" code uses read() instead - but is that not what stdlib uses on the backend? And *does* getchar() ever return EOF on stdin?

Comment: `getchar()` returns `EOF` if you hit `Ctrl-D` and there are no unread characters. Otherwise, the first Ctrl-D returns the unread characters, and a second Ctrl-D returns EOF. The terminal driver permits line editing (as with BackSpace), so it cannot send characters immediately (BackSpace cannot suck them back out of the process). You have to change the terminal mode to get characters as soon as they are available, and stdio does not support that.

Comment: `getchar` is **buffered**, you could change that with [`setvbuf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setvbuf.html); otherwise all you can do is possibly interrupt a read of a *block* of data.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I did try that, in the second example; it made no difference.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I did change the terminal mode, in the third example; I also had buffering disabled on stdin. It didn't make any difference at all. And since you mentioned ^D, I tried it; entering one ^D causes all subsequent ^C signals to print out immediately until the program terminates. I *really* don't understand this behavior.

Comment: @commodorejohn  You might try setting `t.c_lflag |= (NOFLSH);` It looks like the default for SIGINT and some other signals is to flush all input and output immediately.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Thanks, but at this point I've more or less resigned myself to changing my approach. I'm just kind of boggled that there appears to be *no way at all* in plain ANSI C to even determine the status of stdin w.r.t. input being ready/available. The lack of full non-blocking/asynchronous I/O I get, but *this...!?*

Answer (score 0):

This should disable buffering:

```
setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IONBF, (size_t) 0);
```